# what is the equivalent of COM in Mac OS?

Tags: com, macos

I'm new to the world of Mac programming. Can someone please tell me what the equivalent of reusable COM components are in Mac and some links to a good resource to get started (in creating reusable COM-like components and referring those components from a calling app)? Thank you.

Clarification:
- I wish to know if there exist a similar technology, which is supported at OS level.
- I asked the question because I want to port some of my apps (which make use of existing type libraries from Windows as well as those that I make) to Mac.
- Is it possible that I create wrapper classes for my existing (Window) type libraries and refer to them from a Mac app?

Comment: What are the specific requirements? Do you need IPC/marshaling, for example? RPC? Persistent storage? UI embedding? RTTI/DispInvoke/scripting?

Comment: As a started in Mac, RPC, UI embedding is propably too much. But dispatch/invoke/scripting is more likely what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cocoa/Objective-C objects are pretty much all you need.  At a higher level, NIBs can be reusable between applications, although I don't think that is widely done.

You can write plug-ins for Interface Builder to use your own components like the standard ones.

Apple Events and AppleScript are the standard IPC and scripting technologies.

However, unlike COM in the Windows world, there are really no standard conventions for components that interact with one another via standard interfaces, live in standard containers, participate in transactions, etc.  There is no analogue to a type library or IDL (although a scripting dictionary may come close).

Answer (score 5):

I think that [Getting Started with Interapplication Communication](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_InterapplicationCommunication/index.html) from the Mac Dev Center would be a good place to start. There is no direct equivalent to COM/OLE as far as I can tell across the entire OS, but XPCOM and CORBA can be used for some scenarios.

[Distributed Objects Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/DistrObjects.html) is probably the best place to look for conventional Mac solutions to getting apps to talk to each other.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's [XPCOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPCOM).

Comment: XPCOM is a mozilla thing.  Unless you're building browser plug-ins it isn't really relevant.

Comment: One can use XPCOM outside Mozilla, and on binary level it's really mostly just COM (same vtable layout, same base interfaces...). But of course it's not universal, so it can only be used to communicate between two applications that specifically agree on using it.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing quite like COM in Mac OS X (I assume you're talking about OS X, not classic Mac OS). If you want to write reusable components or Cocoa applications, it really is just about as simple as:

1. Write your classes
2. Create a Shared Library project
3. Build the library and distribute it

For the iter-process communication and embedding parts of COM, there isn't anything standardized, really.

Comment: For IPC, OS X has Apple Events/AppleScript and Portable Distributed Objects. Those have been pretty standard for going on two decades now.

Comment: This sounds more like a DLL equivalent than COM.

Comment: @Will -- Well, in a way, what is COM but DLLs + a system for objects and interfaces?  In Mac OS, .dylib provides the former and the objC runtime provides the latter.

Comment: Chuck, while I don't disagree that AppleEvents and PDO *exist* they're not an exact replacement for COM IPC. You could implement an interface enumeration system on PDO, but it doesn't really provide anything out of the box. 

And there isn't anything (to the best of my knowledge) that provides an equivalent to a COM Container. 

Lots of Cocoa apps provide an interface for loadable bundles, but again, there's no enumeration of capabilities (unless the app developer specifies one), and so you can't do tricks like embedding a generic component into multiple apps.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page). Although it won't let you directly reuse your existing Windows-specific COM code, it does give you a similar paradigm of reusable components across different programming languages (any that have a CLI compiler), and even different operating systems (e.g., Windows, Mac, Linux).

I would also recommend [CocoaSharp](http://www.mono-project.com/CocoaSharp) for wiring up directly to the native Mac OS X libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [CFPlugin](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfplugin-rip).

[From Apple statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPlugIns/Concepts/com.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001158-CJBEJBHH) (which now became archived document):

> The plug-in model is compatible with the basics of Microsoft’s COM
> (Component Object Model) architecture. This means that the plug-in
> interface is laid out according to the COM guidelines and that all
> interfaces must inherit from COM’s IUnknown interface. These are the
> only elements plug-ins share with COM. Other COM concepts such as the
> IClassFactory interface, aggregation, out-of-process servers, and
> Windows registry are not mapped. This document only minimally covers
> COM concepts as necessary to explain the way they are used in Core
> Foundation plug-ins. For additional information, you are encouraged to
> seek out the wealth of documentation already published about COM. A
> good place to start is the COM area of Microsoft’s web site,
> http://www.microsoft.com/com/tech/com.asp.

It is initially devoted to a plugin architecture but it seems that it can be used as a COM equivalent, see [this](http://www.macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2004/04/16/com_osx.html?page=1) old post and Chapter 5 (Carbon Plug-ins) of "Mac OS X Advanced Development Techniques " by Joe Zobkiw . Unfortunately I could not find more examples.